# Populate dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which contains following records:

[image]

I need to fill this dataframe with rows with dates which are not present in it.
After inserting new dates the `timestamp` column should be in range `df.timestamp.iloc[0]` and `df.timestamp.iloc[0]`

Comment: Can you post the `dataframe`/`dict` instead of an `image`? you can use `df.head(10).to_dict()`??

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)

Comment: It could also be useful to show an example of the output you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use relativedelta() along with split() from the datetime library